# C++ program called "Palindrome integer" two func. Function 1// Return reversal integer. Function 2// Returns true if palindrome

Tags: function, visual-c++, boolean, palindrome

Please Help

I am writing a program in C++ using visual basic 2010 the program is called "Palindrome integer" I need to write two functions one that//Return the reversal of an integer. For example reverse(456) returns 654
//with header:-->

int reverse(int number)

I need to write another function that//Returns true if number is a palindrome
//with header:-->

bool isPalindrome(int number)

I need to use the reverse function to implement the function isPalindrome. A number is a palindrome if the numbers reversal is the same as itself. My program should report whether the number is a palindrome. Everything is in one file.

I think this program worked when I first wrote the code not as two functions but just directly into int main(). But I must put the code into the specified two functions and once I had done that and made the adjustments I got the following error messages and the black cout display box didn't appear. Here's a snippet of the error report followed by the full error report

: error LNK2005: "int __cdecl reverse(int)" (?reverse@@YAHH@Z) already defined in Driver.obj

:fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I'm getting the following Error Report

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Palindrome integer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 12/7/2013 4:54:25 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Palindrome integer.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>implementation.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl reverse(int)" (?reverse@@YAHH@Z) already defined in Driver.obj
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Palindrome integer\Debug\Palindrome integer.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.25
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

//Bellow is my Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Retun reversal of an integer
int reverse(int number);              //function prototype

//Return true if number is a palindrome
bool isPalindrome(int number);            //function prototype


//Driver
int main()
{
    int usersNumber = 456; //0;    //a few lines commented tempararily for easier number testing
//  cout<<"Enter a number and I'll tell you if it's a Palindrome: ";
//  cin>> usersNumber;

bool palindromeToF = (isPalindrome(usersNumber));

    if (palindromeToF == true)
    {
        cout <<"YES the number is a Palindrome";
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"NO the number is not a Palindrome";
    }


    return 0;
}

//function Implementation
//Retun reversal of an integer
int reverse(int number)
{
    //do while loop to count number of digits in Number
    int digitsCount = 0;
    double exponent1 = 1.0;
    int quotient;

    do
    {
        int tenToPower = pow( 10.0, exponent1);
    //  cout <<"tenToPower  "<< tenToPower <<"\t  ";
        quotient = (number / tenToPower);
    //      cout <<"exponent1  "<< exponent1<<"\t  ";
            exponent1++;

            //cout <<"quotient  "<< quotient<< "\t  "<<endl;
        digitsCount++;
    }while (!quotient == 0);


    //populating array "arrDigits" with integer's digits
    int *arrDigits = NULL;
    arrDigits = new int[digitsCount];
    double exponent2 = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < digitsCount; i++)
        {
        int powerOfTen = pow( 10.0, exponent2);
    //cout <<endl<<"adding "<<((number / powerOfTen) % 10) <<" to sum";
        //cout <<powerOfTen;
        arrDigits[i]= ((number / powerOfTen) % 10);
        exponent2++;
        }

        //reverse number & populate array "arrDigRevers" with reversed order number 
        int *arrDigRevers = NULL;
        arrDigRevers = new int[digitsCount];
        int j = 0;
        int reversedNum = 0;
        double exponent3 = 0.0;
        for(int i = digitsCount-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int powerOfTenB = pow( 10.0, exponent3);
        reversedNum += (powerOfTenB * arrDigits[i]);    //return of reverse func.
        exponent3++;

        /*   //reversed integer put into array 
        if(j < digitsCount)
        {
            arrDigRevers[j] = arrDigits[i];
            //cout <<"\t"<< "arrDigRevers"<<"["<< j<<"]="<< arrDigRevers[j]<<" "<< "arrDigits"<<"["<< j<<"]="<< " "<<arrDigits[j]<<" ";
            j++;
        }
        */

        }

        delete[] arrDigits;
        delete[] arrDigRevers;
        arrDigits = NULL;
        arrDigRevers = NULL;

        //cout <<endl<<"reversed number is "<< reversedNum;

        return reversedNum;
}


//function Implementation 
//Return true if number is a palindrome
bool isPalindrome(int number)
{
    if(number == reverse(number))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: looks like a name clash to me....unambiguate...

Comment: make the name un-ambiguous: i.e. fully qualify the name

Comment: how do I know what name? And by "qualify" do you mean declare

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here:

> `1>implementation.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl reverse(int)" (?reverse@@YAHH@Z) already defined in Driver.obj`

It appears that have defined `int reverse(int number)` in both implementation.cpp and Driver.cpp. You need to rename or remove one of these definitions from your project.

Comment: Your right thanks. I started out trying to write my user defined functions into three files one header file one implementation file and one driver file But then I cloesed all but the driver file thinking it would be easier to test the program in one file. But maybe the other two files remainded open even though I thought I cloesed them or were still linked in some way even though I didn't #include the header in the file I kept open.

Comment: But what ever the reason for the problem I just closed visual basic and reopened it again and opened a new file and pasted my code in and now it works. Thank you again for pointing me back in the right direction.

Comment: When you "closed" `implementation.cpp`, the file persisted on disk and was still included in your project. You need to remove files from your project settings if you don't want them to be included in your build. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee8zw5t(v=vs.90).aspx